Neo4j query on the equality of two properties of two nodes of the same label
First of all I'm sorry if a similar question has already been answered, but I haven't been able to find one.
I'm very new to neo4j, it's my first time using it and my teacher kind of let us fend for ourselves and I have a project where I must built a small database in both SQL and neo4j, and I'm having trouble "translating" my queries from SQL to cypher.
My database has 5 node labels that correspond to their table counterpart in SQL : verb, noun, semantic class and two others which aren't involved here (It's complicated but it's a database on the semantic category of noun and verbs)
Each noun and each verb has a semantic class and has a morphological root. Each semantic class has different properties including the one I'm asking about : "macrocategory". Because different semantic classes can have the same macrocategory.The verbs and the nouns cannot share a semantic class so there's no node related to both a verb and a noun.
So I have these relationships :
(:Verbs)-[IS_A]->(:Semantic_class)
(:Nouns)-[IS_A]->(:Semantic_class)
I'm trying to make a query to return the nouns and verbs which have the same root and have the same macrocategory.
Here's what I tried to do :
MATCH (n:Noms),(v:Verbes) WHERE n.racine = v.racine 
WITH n,v 
MATCH (n)-[EST_UN]->(c:Catégorie_Sémantique), (v)-[EST_UN]->(d:Catégorie_Sémantique) 
WHERE c.macrocatégorie = d.macrocatégorie 
RETURN n,v

It's in french but noms = nouns, racine = root, est_un = is_a, catégorie_sémantique = semantic class, and the rest is self explanatory I think.
The query returns no error but returns nothing at all.
Thank you so much for reading and for your help.

It would be easier to help if you shared some data. There are some improvements you could make to the query e.g. the relationship patterns are missing colons -[:EST_UN]->, but nothing in the syntax that by itself would prevent any results.

Thank you for your reply, I completely forgot about the colons, I added them and it seems the query works now ?? I can't believe I made such a silly mistake and didn't see it, apparently it's important for the query to work. Thank you so much.

Ah, that's it: without the colons they are variable declarations. When you repeat a variable declaration in multiple relationship patterns, then each pattern must bind to the same relationship, which is not possible here.
